# Gmail users.settings REST API odd behavior

Tags: c++, rest, gmail-api, c++builder, chilkat

I am making a REST request to Gmail API.

I am authorized for the scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic`

According to the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/updateImap

Making a `PUT` request to `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/imap` will update the settings.

So I read the settings first (`GET` `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/imap`)

As a result I get this JSON:

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "autoExpunge": false,
  "expungeBehavior": "archive",
  "maxFolderSize": 0
}
```

Then I make modification to the above JSON, enabling "autoExpunge":

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "autoExpunge": true,
  "expungeBehavior": "archive",
  "maxFolderSize": 0
}
```

I make a `PUT` request to `https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/imap` with the body (request body) set to the above JSON.

Something odd happens then.

I get a 200 OK reply back from the server and in the response body I receive back:

```
{
  "enabled": false,
  "autoExpunge": false,
  "expungeBehavior": "archive",
  "maxFolderSize": 0
}
```

So now it is the same, except it has disabled IMAP access (oddly, IMAP access still works). The disabled IMAP setting does show as disabled in the Gmail account settings.

I have tried to make only partial modification request such as:

```
{
  "autoExpunge": true,
}
```

And the returned result is identical as above.

And attempting modifying POP settings (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/updatePop) using similar code additionally results in `204 No Content` error.

For making request I use C++ Builder and CkRest but I don't think that makes any kind of difference.

Is setting modification for IMAP/POP even possible using Gmail REST API? Why is the above happening? Is it a misbehavior?

I think this note from Gmail might be related, though, it should still allow **other** settings modification:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en

> Gmail users with a personal Google Account
>
> In June 2024, the option to choose “Enable IMAP” or “Disable IMAP” won't be available. IMAP access is always turned on in Gmail, and your current connections to other email clients aren’t affected. You don’t need to take any action.